# Game crash with Callback failed because the closure instance has been garbage collected

Tags: java, crash, fullscreen, lwjgl, glfw

I have a problem with my little game. I'm new in LJWGL3 (used 2 for a long time) and want to implement a Key to switch between window and fullscreen mode. I can already do this without big problems. But now my game will crash if I often press this key. Sometimes later or earlier. No timed crash. I try so much (3 hours) and now have run out of ideas. Anybody know what I am doing wrong? I can't post the complete source code because it's to much.
I post down here some important parts of code.
First here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.system.libffi.ClosureError: Callback failed because the closure instance has been garbage collected.
at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeIIPPPP(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1146)
at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1227)
at com.dungeon.gl.FullscreenCreation.setFullScreen(FullscreenCreation.java:63)
at com.dungeon.gl.GLAction.updateGL(GLAction.java:78)
at com.dungeon.MainAction.start(MainAction.java:69)
at com.dungeon.MainAction.main(MainAction.java:21)
```

Here is the code i use to check if the KEY down:

```
    if(glfwGetKey(appID, GLFW_KEY_F) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        FullscreenCreation.setFullScreen(!fullscreen);
    }
```

Here is my FullscreenCreation.java

```
    public static void setFullScreen(boolean fullScreen) {

    //i don't have copy the variables like fullscreen to here
    if (fullscreen == fullScreen)
        return;
    fullscreen = fullScreen; 

    if (fullScreen) {
        windowWIDTH = WIDTH;
        windowHEIGHT = HEIGHT;

        //get monitor resolution
        ByteBuffer vidMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        WIDTH = GLFWvidmode.width(vidMode);
        HEIGHT = GLFWvidmode.height(vidMode);
    } else {
        WIDTH = windowWIDTH;
        HEIGHT = windowHEIGHT;
    }       

    //create new window THIS IS THE POINT WHERE ITS CRASH AFTER A WHILE
    long display = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, MainAction.BASIC_WINDOW_TITLE, fullScreen ? glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() : 0, appID);
    glfwDestroyWindow(appID); //kill the window (for now)

    //add new callback for resizing the window
    glfwSetCallback(display, GLFWWindowSizeCallback(new SAM() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int width, int height) {
            if(width!=0 && height!=0) {
            WIDTH=width;
            HEIGHT=height;
            isResize=true;
            }
        }
    }));


    //now apply the new fullscreen window
    appID = display;

    //some GL stuff for the new window
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(appID);        
    GL.createCapabilities();

    glfwSwapInterval(0); //disable vsync

    //only call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GL_BLEND ...
    DisplayCreation.enableGLStuff();

    isResize = true;
}
```

If you need more code I will post more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a strong reference on every callback you create, because the garbage collector doesn't know it is used in native code and thus collects it otherwise.

So this means you have to store the callback object in a field.

```
private static GLFWWindowSizeCallback sizeCallback;

//...

public static void setFullScreen(boolean fullScreen) {
    //...
    sizeCallback = GLFWWindowSizeCallback(new SAM() {
        //...
    };
    glfwSetCallback(display, sizeCallback);
    //...
}
```

Then, when you are done using the callback (i.e. when you destroy the window), you just have to release it.

```
sizeCallback.release();
```

**Note**: To release all callbacks of a given window, you can also use [Callbacks.glfwReleaseCallbacks](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/Callbacks.html#glfwReleaseCallbacks(long)).

---

For differences between LWJGL 2 and 3 you can have a look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.6-LWJGL3-migration), which also contains a brief explanation of this problem.

Comment: I add this to my game and it work's great. Thank you!